# how to write the test suite for the below function in jasmine , as it contains anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

```
         $( ".pv-firstRange" ).one( "click", function() {
            //making the whole page faded except some elements
            $('#overlay-expose').fadeIn(300, function(){
            $("#range-bubble").fadeOut(1000); 
            $('#searchData').css('z-index','99999');
            });            
            $('#nav').css('z-index','1'); 
            $('#sort-bubble').show();
            setTimeout(function (){   
              $('#nav').css('z-index','1');
              $('#sort-bubble').hide();
              $('#search-bubble').show();
            $('#searchData').css('z-index','1');        
            }, 1500);
           setTimeout(function(){
             setTimeout(function(){
               $('#search-bubble').hide();
           },2000);          
           $('#sort-bubble').hide();
           },2000)
           $('#overlay-expose').fadeOut(5000);                   
           })
```

i am to new jasmine and i have written test suites for this code but checking code coverage results ,this function is not getting executed